# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $a_n\to \infty$ and $a_n+b_n$ is bounded

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $a_n\to \infty$ and $a_n+b_n$ is bounded

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n+b_n}{a_n}=0$$ As $\frac{1}{a_n}\to 0$ and $a_b+b_n$ is bounded.

Therefore: $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{a_n+b_n}}{{a_n}}*\frac{{a_n}}{a_n}=0*\frac{a_n}{a_n}\implies
\\ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{{a_n+b_n}}{a_n}}{\frac{{a_n}}{a_n}}=0*1=0\implies
\\ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{b_n}{a_n}}{1}=0\implies
\\ \lim_{n\to\infty} {1+\frac{b_n}{a_n}}=0\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}=-1
$$

Are those steps correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps are each individually correct, but there is not always a clear connection between one step and the next.

Here is a clearer version of your sequence of equations.
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} &= 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n + b_n - a_n}{a_n} 
\\ & = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n + b_n}{a_n} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n}
\\ & = 0 - 1 = -1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: We use the fact that if $\lim x_n\to L$ then $\lim \frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{1}{L}$?

Comment: Yes: to finish, it suffices to use the fact that if $x_n \to L$, then $1/x_{n} \to 1/L$. I intentionally reached the same conclusion that you did, so I had assumed that you already had this in mind.

Comment: But that can only be use if we know that $L\neq 0$. We can not know from the start that we can use it on $lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ as it can be equal to zero for example

Comment: @newhere But we just proved that $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = -1$, so of course we know that $L \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok I see. That is why I started with a limit that I know that exists and then move forward

Answer (score 1):

From your first conclusion, for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N_\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $n>N_\varepsilon$
$$
\left| {\frac{{a_n  + b_n }}{{a_n }}} \right| \le \varepsilon  \Leftrightarrow \left| {1 + \frac{{b_n }}{{a_n }}} \right| \le \varepsilon  \Leftrightarrow \left| {\frac{{b_n }}{{a_n }} - ( - 1)} \right| \le \varepsilon .
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{{b_n }}{{a_n }} \to  - 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

see that you also have $b_n \to\infty $ because the sum $a_n+b_n$ bounded.
so, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n+b_n}{b_n}=0=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=-1  $

Comment: Why can we conclude that $b_n\to \infty$ ?

Comment: @aud098 Presumably you mean that $b_n \to -\infty$

Comment: it could be both $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ since $a_n \to +\infty $ and $a_n\to -\infty$

Comment: @newwhere otherwise see $a_n+b_n$ won't be bounded. can you see why?

Comment: @aud098 In the context of introductory calculus, $\infty$ specifically means $+\infty$.  So, the statements $a_n \to \infty$ and $a_n \to +\infty$ have the same meaning.

Comment: but it should mean both positive or negative.

Comment: @aud098 Perhaps, but that is not what it actually means.

Comment: if you are assuming $x \to \a \implies x \to \a_+$ then nothing to say.